# Questions about the table sideways in Latex

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

My table is very big, so I have to put it sideways in latex. this is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Asset for each operation}
    \label{tab:changeOverCost}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccccccccccccc}
        & Finger Gripper 1 & Finger Gripper 2 & Finger Gripper 3 & Finger Gripper 4 & Drilling end effector 1 & Drilling end effector 2 & Drilling end effector 3 & Drilling end effector 4 & V-STARS & Leica Metrology & Metrology & Marker 1 & Marker 2 & Marker 3\\
        \hline
        Finger Gripper 1 & ? & &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Finger Gripper 2 & ?&  &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Finger Gripper 3 & ? &  &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Finger Gripper 4 & ? &  &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Drilling end effector 1 &  & ? &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Drilling end effector 2 &  & ? &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Drilling end effector 3 &  & ? &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Drilling end effector 4 &  & ? &  & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        V-Star &  &  & ? & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Leica Metrology &  &  & ? & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Marker 1 &  &  &  & ? & & & & & & & & & &\\
        Marker 2 &  &  &  & ?& & & & & & & & & &\\
        Marker 3 &  &  &  & ?& & & & & & & & & &\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

May I ask, how to make the column in the latex pdf match the size, in my current use case, the pdf can't show all the columns. Besides, any idea about how to make the table nicer?

Answer (score 1):

My main suggestion is to provide some grouping in the header row and to omit repetitive material as much as possible. I further suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and assign equal widths to the 14 data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as appropriate
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
    \caption{Asset for each operation}
    \label{tab:changeOverCost}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} r @{\quad} *{14}{C} }
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Finger Gripper} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Drilling end effector} 
        & V-Stars 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Metrology}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Marker}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-5}   \cmidrule(lr){6-9} 
        \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(l){13-15}
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & Leica & Other & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \midrule
        Finger Gripper 1        & ?& & & &  & & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        Finger Gripper 2        & ?& & & &  & & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        Finger Gripper 3        & ?& & & &  & & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        Finger Gripper 4        & ?& & & &  & & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        \addlinespace
        Drilling end effector 1 &  & & & & ?& & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        Drilling end effector 2 &  & & & & ?& & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        Drilling end effector 3 &  & & & & ?& & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        Drilling end effector 4 &  & & & & ?& & & &  & & &  & &  \\
        \addlinespace
        V-Stars                 &  & & & &  & & & & ?& & &  & &  \\
        Metrology-Leica         &  & & & &  & & & & ?& & &  & &  \\
        Metrology-Other         &  & & & &  & & & & ?& & &  & &  \\
        \addlinespace
        Marker 1                &  & & & &  & & & &  & & & ?& &  \\
        Marker 2                &  & & & &  & & & &  & & & ?& &  \\
        Marker 3                &  & & & &  & & & &  & & & ?& &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```